# Tkinter (or CustomTkinter) scrollbar transparency

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I want to hide scrollbar in CTkScrollableFrame, or at least make it transparent. Anticipating your question, I need to be able to scroll my frame with mouse wheel, so I don't need to see the scroll button. Is there any way to do it?

I just read wiki for both Ctk and Tkinter, and didn't find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to hide it, then just don't create it. You can still scroll scrollable objects without having to create an invisible scrollbar.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I suppose you're talking about bind() and yview(), found it in the docs